# Biot-Savart Law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors

Today we started learning about Biot-Savart law. While deriving the formula, our professor listed out a bunch of relations, which have been *experimentally determined*,

->dB is directly proportional to current, length of  element, and inversely proportional to square of distance.

This all seemed ok and relatable, and  then he wrote another proportionality-> dB is directly proportional to sine of angle between position vector and current flow.

This seemed completely non intuitive to me. Is there any logical way of deducing this?

Comment: Have you learned about the cross product between two vectors?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean when you ask for a *logical deduction* of facts presented to you as *experimentally determined*. Typically, such "experimental facts" serve as the *input* to a theory from which further things are then deduced. From what other facts do you want this to be deduced?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I do know....you may tell it just comes from the cross product of dl and I but during the derivation they were found individually

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have seen a few places where it's been mentioned like this has something to do with relativity, and thus out of the scope of syllabus

Comment: I was just asking how do you put out randomly that it's proportional to sine of an angle..... I can't just digest that fact

Comment: Well, just like the aforementioned proportional relationships, isn’t *”$dB$ is directly proportional to sine of angle…”* also something that can be experimentally observed?

Comment: Basically the Biot-Savart law is a special case of a solution of the Maxwell equations. However it is a bit complicated since it demands mathematical formalism (Green function). It is usually taught much later.

Comment: Current create circular magnetic field. It is proportional to $1/r^2$, since if on take concentrated circles the energy should be conserved (surface $2 \pi r^2$).

Comment: Also the more element with length $dl$ one have, the higher the field (if the orientation of elements does not cancel each other due to the orientation)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I will think from the mathematical point of view. Magnetic field, current flow and position vector are all vector quantities. Hence, mathematically, it must be done in "vectorial" way. Vectors multiplication that result a vector is cross product. And mathematically, cross product is proportional to the $sine$ of the angle between the two vectors multiplied.

Comment: Hmm mathematically it seems ok but how do you explain it practically?

Answer (score 0):

The Biot-Savart law is derived from experiment. It cannot be obtained by logic alone, except from other theoretical formulations that also derive from experiment.
Nobody had any 'logical' intuition for magnetic fields generated by currents before they were discovered by Oersted in 1820, preceded by Romagnosi in 1802, and even Oersted did not have such an intuition and he was unable to give a theoretical explanation nor a mathematical model.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian_Domenico_Romagnosi